# Adding google font to tinyMCE

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a google font to tinymce. I can not get this to work at all. Here is my current example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor",
    font_formats: 'Libre Barcode 128=Libre Barcode 128, cursive',
    content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+128',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ]
});
```

Demo using tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/iagaab

Demo using jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tx4Lc8a9/46/

This is the font in question i'm trying to get to work https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+128

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code works if you just update the version of TinyMCE to the Latest one:
https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4puwmbc/

```
    <form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
            toolbar: "styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor",
            font_formats: 'Libre Barcode 128=Libre Barcode 128, cursive',
            content_css: [
                '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+128',
                '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
            ]
        });
    </script>
```